# NopCommerce webservice DTO's

Tags: automapper, dto, nopcommerce

I am trying to extend webservice plygin in order to get from nopcommerce the List of Products.

What I have done is the following. I created a class like `ProductDto`,  and inside `NopService.cs` I created a method like:

```
public List<ProductDto> GetProductCollection(string usernameOrEmail, string userPassword)
```

`ProductDto` is taken from `Product` using AutoMapper. (shown below)

BUT IT DOES NOT WORK :(  what am I missing?

Any ideas? The idea behind all this is to connect nopcommerce with my ERP through webservices

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog
{
    public class ProductDto
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        // Instance members must be virtual on data table objects like Affiliate.cs
        // Virtual is required by data access frameworks so that these frameworks
        // can implement more complex features like lazy loading.

        public virtual string ProductGID { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the short description
        /// </summary>

        public virtual string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the full description
        /// </summary>

        public virtual string FullDescription { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the admin comment
        /// </summary>

        public virtual string AdminComment { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value of used product template identifier
        /// </summary>

        public virtual int ProductTemplateId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether to show the product on home page
        /// </summary>

        public virtual bool ShowOnHomePage { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the meta keywords
        /// </summary>

        public virtual string MetaKeywords { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the meta description
        /// </summary>

        public virtual string MetaDescription { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the meta title
        /// </summary>

        public virtual string MetaTitle { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the search-engine name
        /// </summary>

        public virtual string SeName { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the product allows customer reviews
        /// </summary>

        public virtual bool AllowCustomerReviews { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the rating sum (approved reviews)
        /// </summary>

        public virtual int ApprovedRatingSum { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the rating sum (not approved reviews)
        /// </summary>

        public virtual int NotApprovedRatingSum { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the total rating votes (approved reviews)
        /// </summary>

        public virtual int ApprovedTotalReviews { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the total rating votes (not approved reviews)
        /// </summary>

        public virtual int NotApprovedTotalReviews { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the entity is published
        /// </summary>

        public virtual bool Published { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the entity has been deleted
        /// </summary>

        public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date and time of product creation
        /// </summary>

        public virtual DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the date and time of product update
        /// </summary>

        public virtual DateTime UpdatedOnUtc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And inside NopService.cs I created a method like this

```
public List<ProductDto> GetProductCollection(string usernameOrEmail, string userPassword)
    {
        CheckAccess(usernameOrEmail, userPassword);
        if (!_permissionSettings.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCatalog))
            throw new ApplicationException("Not allowed to manage Catalog");

        var productslist = new List<Product>();
        productslist.AddRange(_productService.GetAllProducts(false));
        List<Product> products = productslist;
        List<ProductDto> productsDtos = Mapper.Map<List<Product>, List<ProductDto>>(products);

        return productsDtos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your mapping configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping should only be configured once, during startup. So try moving it to a profile:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using AutoMapper;

    public class ProductProfile : Profile
    {
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get
            {
                return "ProductProfile";
            }
        }

        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<ProductCategory, ProductCategoryDto>();
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Then initialise it during start up (`Application_Start`, etc):

```cs
Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<ProductProfile>());
```

Create a unit test to check your mappings:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using AutoMapper;

    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class AutoMapperTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<ProductProfile>());
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }
}
```

This will help determine if there are any errors in your mapping configuration, and show you what to fix. Once this is done, you can then focus on getting the functionality working.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work but with problems in mapping nested classes.

Product class

```
public partial class Product : BaseEntity, ILocalizedEntity
{


    private ICollection<ProductVariant> _productVariants;


    private ICollection<ProductCategory> _productCategories;


    private ICollection<ProductManufacturer> _productManufacturers;


    private ICollection<ProductPicture> _productPictures;


    private ICollection<ProductReview> _productReviews;


    private ICollection<ProductSpecificationAttribute> _productSpecificationAttributes;


    private ICollection<ProductTag> _productTags;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    // Instance members must be virtual on data table objects like Affiliate.cs
    // Virtual is required by data access frameworks so that these frameworks
    // can implement more complex features like lazy loading.

    public virtual string ProductGID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the short description
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the full description
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string FullDescription { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the admin comment
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string AdminComment { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value of used product template identifier
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int ProductTemplateId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether to show the product on home page
    /// </summary>

    public virtual bool ShowOnHomePage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the meta keywords
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string MetaKeywords { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the meta description
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string MetaDescription { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the meta title
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string MetaTitle { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the search-engine name
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string SeName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the product allows customer reviews
    /// </summary>

    public virtual bool AllowCustomerReviews { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the rating sum (approved reviews)
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int ApprovedRatingSum { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the rating sum (not approved reviews)
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int NotApprovedRatingSum { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the total rating votes (approved reviews)
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int ApprovedTotalReviews { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the total rating votes (not approved reviews)
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int NotApprovedTotalReviews { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the entity is published
    /// </summary>

    public virtual bool Published { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the entity has been deleted
    /// </summary>

    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time of product creation
    /// </summary>

    public virtual DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time of product update
    /// </summary>

    public virtual DateTime UpdatedOnUtc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the product variants
    /// </summary>


    public virtual ICollection<ProductVariant> ProductVariants
    {
        get { return _productVariants ?? (_productVariants = new List<ProductVariant>()); }
        protected set { _productVariants = value; }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of ProductCategory
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories
    {
        get { return _productCategories ?? (_productCategories = new List<ProductCategory>()); }
        protected set { _productCategories = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of ProductManufacturer
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ProductManufacturer> ProductManufacturers
    {
        get { return _productManufacturers ?? (_productManufacturers = new List<ProductManufacturer>()); }
        protected set { _productManufacturers = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of ProductPicture
    /// </summary>

    public virtual ICollection<ProductPicture> ProductPictures
    {
        get { return _productPictures ?? (_productPictures = new List<ProductPicture>()); }
        protected set { _productPictures = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of product reviews
    /// </summary>

    public virtual ICollection<ProductReview> ProductReviews
    {
        get { return _productReviews ?? (_productReviews = new List<ProductReview>()); }
        protected set { _productReviews = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the product specification attribute
    /// </summary>

    public virtual ICollection<ProductSpecificationAttribute> ProductSpecificationAttributes
    {
        get { return _productSpecificationAttributes ?? (_productSpecificationAttributes = new List<ProductSpecificationAttribute>()); }
        protected set { _productSpecificationAttributes = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the product specification attribute
    /// </summary>

    public virtual ICollection<ProductTag> ProductTags
    {
        get { return _productTags ?? (_productTags = new List<ProductTag>()); }
        protected set { _productTags = value; }
    }

}
```

}

ProductDto Class

```
public class ProductDto
{



    private ICollection<ProductCategoryDto> _productCategories;




    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    // Instance members must be virtual on data table objects like Affiliate.cs
    // Virtual is required by data access frameworks so that these frameworks
    // can implement more complex features like lazy loading.

    public virtual string ProductGID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the short description
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the full description
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string FullDescription { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the admin comment
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string AdminComment { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value of used product template identifier
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int ProductTemplateId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether to show the product on home page
    /// </summary>

    public virtual bool ShowOnHomePage { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the meta keywords
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string MetaKeywords { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the meta description
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string MetaDescription { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the meta title
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string MetaTitle { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the search-engine name
    /// </summary>

    public virtual string SeName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the product allows customer reviews
    /// </summary>

    public virtual bool AllowCustomerReviews { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the rating sum (approved reviews)
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int ApprovedRatingSum { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the rating sum (not approved reviews)
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int NotApprovedRatingSum { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the total rating votes (approved reviews)
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int ApprovedTotalReviews { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the total rating votes (not approved reviews)
    /// </summary>

    public virtual int NotApprovedTotalReviews { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the entity is published
    /// </summary>

    public virtual bool Published { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the entity has been deleted
    /// </summary>

    public virtual bool Deleted { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time of product creation
    /// </summary>

    public virtual DateTime CreatedOnUtc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the date and time of product update
    /// </summary>

    public virtual DateTime UpdatedOnUtc { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the collection of ProductCategory
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<ProductCategoryDto> ProductCategories
    {
        get { return _productCategories ?? (_productCategories = new List<ProductCategoryDto>()); }
        protected set { _productCategories = value; }
    }



}
```

}

ProductCategory Class

```
public partial class ProductCategory : BaseEntity
{
     public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the category identifier
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the product is featured
    /// </summary>
     public virtual bool IsFeaturedProduct { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the display order
    /// </summary>
     public virtual int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the category
    /// </summary>
     public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the product
    /// </summary>
     public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

}
```

And ProductCategoryDto Class

```
public class ProductCategoryDto

{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the product identifier
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the category identifier
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether the product is featured
    /// </summary>
    public virtual bool IsFeaturedProduct { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the display order
    /// </summary>
    public virtual int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the category
    /// </summary>
    public virtual CategoryDto Category { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the product
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ProductDto Product { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping is done inside a method like this

```
public List<ProductDto> GetProductCollection(string usernameOrEmail, string userPassword)

    {
        CheckAccess(usernameOrEmail, userPassword);
        if (!_permissionSettings.Authorize(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCatalog))
            throw new ApplicationException("Not allowed to manage Catalog");

        List<Product> productslist = new List<Product>();
        productslist.AddRange(_productService.GetAllProducts(false));
        List<ProductCategory> productCategorylist = new List<ProductCategory>();
        foreach (var product in productslist)
        {
            productCategorylist.AddRange(_categoryService.GetProductCategoriesByProductId(product.Id, false));


        }



        Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<ProductCategory, ProductCategoryDto>();
        List<ProductDto> productsDto = Mapper.Map<List<Product>, List<ProductDto>>(productslist);
        List<ProductCategoryDto> productCategoriesDto = Mapper.Map<List<ProductCategory>, List<ProductCategoryDto>>(productCategorylist);


        return productsDto;

    }
```

The problem is that I never get the mapping from ProductDto to the Icollection Of ProductCategoriesDto. Everything else works fine.

Comment: I managed to make it work by changing this private ICollection<ProductCategoryDto> _productCategories; in ProductDto class into public ICollection<ProductCategoryDto> _productCategories; Now I can navigate from products to productCategories but I get Http error when I try to transfer ProductDto Objects via web services